# python script to download text files from google cloud storage, If I have service account id and private key

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, google-cloud-storage, boto, gsutil

I have 3 things:

Service account ID, private key and Bucket Name.
I have to download some text files(objects) from this bucket to my local system.

I need a python script for this.

I want code something like this:

import requests
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
import os
import shutil
import StringIO
import tempfile
import time

gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin.SetFallbackClientIdAndSecret(serviceAccountId, privateKey)


don't know the below code.

Comment: please help If someone knows the solution